# storing Int in swift 2

Tags: swift, input, numbers, sum

I am new to swift so need some help. want to get a number from text field (which input by user) and sum it then store it for the next time. So when user come back in other time and input another number will be summed to the previous number.

let say, user input 10 and close the app then come back and input 5. the app will sum them and give 15 so on and so forth.

thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NSUserDefault` to save the value.

Example : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults

Write :

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(10, forKey: "value")
```

Read :

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let value = defaults.integerForKey("value")
```

You can also use code data : https://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: NSUserDefaults has a specific method called integerForKey for loading Integers

Comment: No need to force synchronization

Comment: many thanks for your support. however, the number will be provided by users so it might be any number

Comment: I would like to build an app which calculate expenses my problem is how to accumulate all numbers and save them then get the value by the end of the month. appreciate your help in this one with a little details I know no much.

Comment: You can store an array of int with key "January" for example and at the end of the month you can calculate the sum for this array.

Comment: yeah it will work so can you give example ? sorry I am troubling you

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a database (e.g. CoreData) or a UIDocument/NSDocument

Comment: // Add value for january

let valueToAdd1 = 12

let valueToAdd2 = 15

let defaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var january : NSMutableArray? = defaults.objectForKey("January") as? NSMutableArray

if (january == nil) {
    january = NSMutableArray()
}

january?.addObject(valueToAdd1)

january?.addObject(valueToAdd2)

defaults.setObject(january, forKey: "January")

// Get all values for january

var total = 0

if (january != nil) {
    for num in january! {
        total += Int(num as! NSNumber)
    }
}

Comment: 'Core Data` or `Realm` will do this, and there are plenty of tutorials available

Comment: I'd recommend this [Core Data Playground](https://github.com/andyshep/CoreDataPlayground) as a way to get started.

Answer (score -1):

many thanks for you all

I just found the best way. I just used this code

first read it:

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let X = defaults.integerForKey("Cost")

convert the field.text! in to integer and add the previous value "X"

```
        Cost = integer! + X
```

re-write the default

```
        defaults.setValue(Cost, forKey: "Cost")
        defaults.synchronize()
```

done